# Difference between Occur.SHOULD and Occur.MUST in SOLR

Tags: solr

I don't get the distinction between Occur.SHOULD and Occur.MUST in add method of org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery. Can anybody explain?

Comment: Have a read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122733/difference-between-booleanclause-occur-must-and-booleanclause-occur-should-in-lu. This is exactly the same question and has been answered quite well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BooleanClause.Occur.Must` stands for a `Mandatory` clause. The Clause should be met for the result to be returned. Basically `AND`.

`BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD` stands for the `optional` clause and would behave like an `OR`

For Solr `BooleanClause.Occur.Must` are marked with `+` in the debug query explanation whereas the `BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD` have no sign associated with it.